# AutoHotKey Array Confusion

Tags: arrays, automation, autohotkey

I want to ask is the following code two different array? Or is it the same array? In AutoHotKey I am confused how to create two different arrays. I use a really old version of the AutoHotKey, ver 1.0.47.06...

```
; Keep track of the number of discharge cases
date_array_count := 0

; Keep track of the discharge cases date
case_array_count := 0

Array%date_array_count% := "01/01/2014"
Array@case_array_count% := 1001001
```

And furthermore, if I have a variable, I use = to assign it to the array? Or use :=?

```
discharge_date := "01/01/2014"
Array%date_array_count% = discharge_date
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those aren't actual "*arrays*", they're called *pseduo-arrays* and are an old way to create arrays. You can read more about them [here](http://ahkscript.org/docs/misc/Arrays.htm#pseudo).

In your case, those would be the same array, yes. You're using `Array` as your array-variable, and `date_array_count` and `case_array_count` as the index. Both of which are zero, so you're putting both values at the same index, meaning you'll overwrite your first value.

As for assigning values, try to always use `:=`. When you want to assign a string, quote the string like this: `myVariable := "Hello world!"`.

---

*"Real"* arrays were added to AHK in a later version, which I **strongly** suggest you upgrade to. You can get the latest version from here - http://ahkscript.org/

Once you have the latest version, you can read more about arrays in the docs - http://ahkscript.org/docs/misc/Arrays.htm

Here's a basic example of how to work with arrays:

```
; Create an array
myArray := []

; Add values to the array
myArray.insert("cat")
myArray.insert("dog")
myArray.insert("dragon")

; Loop through the array
for each, value in myArray {
    ; each holds the index
    ; value holds the value at that index
    msgBox, Ittr: %each%, Value: %value%
}

; Get a specific item from the array
msgBox % myArray[2]

; Remove a value from the array at a set index
myArray.remove(1)

; Loop through the array
for each, value in myArray {
    ; each holds the index
    ; value holds the value at that index
    msgBox, Ittr: %each%, Value: %value%
}
```

You can also assign values to arrays like this:

```
index := 1
myVariable := "my other value"

myArray[index] := "my value" ; Puts "my value" at index "1" in the array
myArray[index] := myVariable ; Puts "my other value" at index "1" in the array
```

---

**Edit:**

If you're unable to upgrade, this is how you achieve and work with multiple *pseduo-arrays*:

```
; Create our index variables
dateIndex := 0
caseIndex := 0

; Create our two arrays
dateArray := ""
caseArray := ""

; Increment the index before adding a value
dateIndex++
; Add values to the array using the index variable
dateArray%dateIndex% := "01/01/2014"

caseIndex++
caseArray%caseIndex% := 1001001

; Loop through the array, use the index as the loop-count
Loop % dateIndex
{
    ; A_Index contains the current loop-index
    msgBox % dateArray%A_Index%
}

Loop % caseIndex
{
    msgBox % caseArray%A_Index%
}
```

And if you want to arrays to share the same index:

```
; Create index variable
arrIndex := 0

; Create our two arrays
dateArray := ""
caseArray := ""

; Increment the index before adding a value
arrIndex++

; Add values to the array using the index variable
dateArray%arrIndex% := "01/01/2014"
caseArray%arrIndex% := 1001001

arrIndex++
dateArray%arrIndex% := "02/02/2014"
caseArray%arrIndex% := 999999

; Loop through the array, use the index as the loop-count
Loop % arrIndex
{
    ; A_Index contains the current loop-index
    msgBox % dateArray%A_Index% "`n" caseArray%A_Index%
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the great answer, but it is company software, I am unable to upgrade. In order version, is there a way to create multiple arrays?